# Windows Command Prompt: Moving multiple sub-files to their respective parent folders

Tags: command-line

So, I would like to achieve the following:
The file structure currently looks like this:

Parent

Folder A

```
  Folder Aa

     File 1
```

Folder B

```
  Folder Bb

     File 2
```

Folder C

```
  Folder Cc

     File 3
```

and I would like to run a command which converts this into:

Parent

Folder A

```
  Folder Aa

  File 1
```

Folder B

```
  Folder Bb

  File 2
```

Folder C

```
  Folder Cc

  File 3
```

i.e. the files have simply been moved up to their respective parent folders. I have found code where you can group many sub-files into one single folder, but not where they all go into their individual folders.
I guess it would be a variation of:
for %F in (c:\foo\bar*.*) do move /Y %F c:\foo
?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are there files at any level other than the bottom level?

Comment: No, folders A, B, C are empty other than the folder within it (which are useless and just causing problems!) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple .bat file in the directory where all `FolderA`, `FolderB`, ... reside

```
@echo off

for /D %%f in (Folder*) do (
  for /D %%g in (%%f\*) do (
     move %%g\*.* %%f
  )
)
```

this loops on the directories, then on the inner directories, and apply the global move command of all files one level up.